# Facebook Share button - To share the page contents instead of page URL

Tags: facebook, api, share

I using the Facebook Share button. It works fine with this code

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.sample.com" target="_blank">
  Share on Facebook
</a></li>.
```

But this code is sharing the page URL alone. But I need to share the images and email exists on that sharing page. How to do this ?. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="fb('www.google.com','abcd')" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="<?php echo WEBSITE_IMG_URL; ?>fb.jpg" width="34" height="34"  alt=""/></a>


(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
function fb(url,title) {
var currentURL    =    encodeURIComponent(url);
window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+currentURL,"","height=368,width=600,left=100,top=100,menubar=0");

}
```

Comment: image share successfully.